# Get the string rows of dataframe as an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, each rows has a string like (without space between the values) `[1 2 3 4 5]`. I want to get the rows as an array. Here is part of my data frame

[image]

Here is an example of my data frame:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['b'] = [str([1 2]), str([2 3 4 5 6 7]), str([2 3 4 5])]
```

The output which I want is, for example row with index 1 is:

```
row_2 = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

could you please help me with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store everything this way.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['b'] = ["12", "234567", "2345"]

arr=[]
for i in df['b']:
  arr.append([int(j) for j in i])

print(arr)
```